# Validate AWS-SAM Template/Reduce turnaround time to find errors

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, serverless, aws-sam

I just got an error after deploying a large SAM template with a wrong keyword.

Instead of `ServerSideEncryptionByDefault` I wrote `ServerSideEncryptionDefault` (missing `By`).

```
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketEncryption:
        ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration:
          - ServerSideEncryptionDefault:
              SSEAlgorithm: AES256
```

The turnaround time to get this error is about a minute, because CloudFormation first handles all the other resources and finds this error late in my deployment.

Is it possible to have a linter or something check the code before I start a deployment?

I only found `sam validate` which doesn't find these kind of errors (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-validate.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The CloudFormation Linter](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint) catches this with:

`E3002 Invalid Property Resources/Bucket/Properties/BucketEncryption/ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration/0/ServerSideEncryptionDefault`

[The CloudFormation Linter Visual Studio Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kddejong.vscode-cfn-lint) runs the linter on every file save if you have both installed